# Delete pairs of rows based on value in column

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

A testing machine tests parts at two different speeds: 50 and 200 rpm. The machine outputs the data for each part at each speed such that

Row 1 = part 1 at 50 rpm
Row 2 = part 1 at 200 rpm
Row 3 = part 2 at 50 rpm
Row 4 = part 2 at 200 rpm

and so on for about 23,000 parts.

If a part number failed for a specific speed, the data would show "n.i.O." in column H of that row, but it would only show it for that speed. I'm trying to write a macro that will check if a row contains the "n.i.O." value, and then delete both that row, and the row for the other speed. Here's the code I have so far:

```
Sub DeleteFailures()

Dim r As Long

Dim lastrow As Long

lastrow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

For r = 1 To lastrow

    If Cells(r, "H").Value = "n.i.O." Then

        If Cells(r, "E").Value = "50" Then

            Rows(r + 1).EntireRow.Delete

            Rows(r).EntireRow.Delete

        ElseIf Cells(r, "E").Value = "200" Then

            Rows(r - 1).EntireRow.Delete

            Rows(r).EntireRow.Delete

        End If

    Else

    End If

Next

End Sub
```

This doesn't seem to want to work for me. I think the problem might be that it skips a row every time one is deleted, but I'm not sure. Is there another approach that might work better?

Comment: Thanks for fixing my post. I'm not sure why the formatting got all weird.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's exactly the reason you're thinking about. To make it work you should loop beginning the bottom:

```
For r = lastrow To 1 Step -1
```

The whole `For` loop block I believe should look like this (changed `ElseIf` part):

```
For r = lastrow To 1 Step -1
    If Cells(r, "H").Value = "n.i.O." Then
        If Cells(r, "E").Value = "50" Then
            Rows(r + 1).EntireRow.Delete
            Rows(r).EntireRow.Delete
        ElseIf Cells(r, "E").Value = "200" Then
            Rows(r).EntireRow.Delete
            Rows(r - 1).EntireRow.Delete
            r = r - 1
        End If
    Else
    End If
Next
```

Comment: I was actually just about to post a comment saying I had figured out the problem. This is exactly what I ended up doing. When the code read an "n.i.O." on a 200 speed line, it deleted the row before it, indexing everything up, and thus changing which line "r" was referring to at that time. Then it deleted the "r" row, which was then the row after the one that was supposed to be deleted. But thank you for your answer!

Comment: I do have 1 more question. I have to run this macro several times before it will actually remove all of the "n.i.O." rows. Is there a reason that it misses some rows? And is there a way to fix that?

Comment: Did you use the exact copy of my answer? Notice that I changed the order in `ElseIf` and introduced one additional line.

Comment: You're absolutely right. I hadn't noticed that. I tried your code and it worked perfectly. Thank you.